# convert a multidimensionnal array into another one but only just with values for highcharts library

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, highcharts

I have an array `$array` which returns me this when I make a `var_dump($array);` :

```
array (size=24)
  0 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2015-05-05 00:03:08' (length=19)
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2015-05-05 01:19:34' (length=19)
  2 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2015-05-05 02:44:16' (length=19)
  3 =>
    /*............. etc ........*/
  23 =>
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '24' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2015-05-05 08:32:05' (length=19

)
```

For Highcharts.js, I need to pass with json another multidimensionnal array only with values. I have to make sure that the highcharts library understand that I have a value for xAxis such as date, and a value for yAxis such as a int.

Now I am trying to stock in another variable `$data` all values of the multidimensionnal array `$array`, but I need to stock this values like this result (arrays in array only with value):

```
$data = [ ['id','date'], ['id','date'],  /*...etc*/]
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: What will be the difference between those arrays?

Comment: just get only the values to returns them in json for highcharts.js (x date and y id)

Comment: You just dont need the keys?

Comment: yes, I just only need the values. In highcharts.js, for xAxis there is the categories, but these categories are statics, that's why for the chart I need to pass with json an array like this `$data = [ ['id','date'], ['id','date'],  /*...etc*/]` in order to have the xAxis values for the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loop and generate new array -

```
foreach($yourArray as $array) {
   $newArray[] = array_values($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with the following code :

```
$array = array(
    ...
);

function transform($item)
{
    return array_values($item);
}

$newArray = array_map("transform", $array);
```

It will output in `$newArray`:

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    string(19) "2015-05-05 00:03:08"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    string(19) "2015-05-05 01:19:34"
  }
  ...
}
```

Reference :

- [`array_map` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`array_values` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)